# Where is my implementation of rot13 in JavaScript going wrong?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, rot13

Code in question with syntax highlighting here: [via Friendpaste](http://friendpaste.com/7EbFwfzYSemBxmL2u5879f)

rot13.js:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <script>
> String.prototype.rot13 = rot13 = function(s)
>  {
>     return (s = (s) ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
>      {
>         if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
>         c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
>         k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96) % 26 + 13;
>         return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
>      }).join('');
>  };
> </script>
> ```

As you can see, using quite literally a single line to attach a method to the String object a la prototyping, I'm having a map() method that I previously set up (I know for sure that that code works perfectly; it's simply iterating over each element in the array and applying the function specified in the parameter) go over each character in a string and do what I thought were the proper calculations to transform the string into it's rot13'd counterpart. I was sadly mistaken. Can anybody spot where I went wrong?

Comment: What's the incorrect result that you're getting?

Comment: For example, 'Bacon'.rot13() is coming out to 'Onp|{' when it should be 'Onpba'...

Comment: So how are you sure that inner function works perfectly?

Comment: "I know for sure that that code works perfectly": this belief is a sign that you haven't programmed enough. :-)

Comment: "my one-line implementation" that is not a virtue.

Comment: Next to what @phant0m said… how does this even constitute "one-line implementation"?

Answer (score 78):

You could use the super-short:

```
s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});
```

Comment: Just spotted that your code is being used on rot13.com now

Comment: Since this seems to be a golfed answer: You can make it two characters shorter by replacing `/[A-Za-z]/g` with `/[A-Z]/gi` or `/[a-z]/gi`. Did case insensitive RegExp not exist in JavaScript in 2009?

Comment: @Howard [rot13.com](https://rot13.com) guys forget to check their "improvement", this formula works for `rot13`, but they decided to implement `rot1` and up to `rot25` without thinking too much, and as result they lost primary gist of `rot13` - reversibility :) So, keep in mind, - their solutions works only for `rot13`

Comment: Here's a version that does rot by whatever number you want.

`s.replace(/[a-z]/ig, (c)=>{let n=c.charCodeAt(0);let l=n&0x1F-1;return String.fromCharCode(n-l+(l+13)%26);})`

Just change `13` to the number you want to rot by. It's also a few characters shorter.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a solution using `replace` and `indexOf` functions:

```
function rot13(s) {
  return s.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, c =>
    "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"[
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(c) ] )
}
```

This is made up of:

- `/[A-Z]/gi` regular expression for matching only characters
- `replace` is used to substitute those characters
- an a replacer function written as an arrow function
- `indexOf` is to convert the character into a numeric lookup index
- we lookup the index in the substitution array and we're done

Answer (score 16):

This gives correct results.

```js
function rot13(s)
 {
    return (s ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
     {
        if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
        c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
        k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 83) % 26 || 26;
        return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
     }).join('');
 }
 
 alert(rot13(rot13("Mark this as accepted answer :)")));
```

Comment: @Hexagon -- no accepted answer?  [Zibri's here seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/NBUn9/).

Comment: From the many answers on here, I tried this one first and it worked well, it worked also well in combination with PHP's `str_rot13()`.

Comment: @ruffin -- This fails on strings that include an underscore '_'

Answer (score 13):

Just because it's even shorter and also more understandable/logical:

```
function rot13(s) {
  return s.replace( /[A-Za-z]/g , function(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode( c.charCodeAt(0) + ( c.toUpperCase() <= "M" ? 13 : -13 ) );
  } );
}
```

Comment: Ouch! Feel ashamed, I should have done this simple test. Only small correction needed: '<=' instead of '<'. Now it works fine!

Comment: `/[A-z]/` also looks fishy to me.

Comment: @Rhymoid If you meant **"`[A-z]` is wrong"**, then I (again shamefully) agree... I got `[A-z]` from the (very useful) site www.w3schools.com, but when I test it, I see that this range also contains some special characters, like backslash and underscore... So I changed it to `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Worth noting that the original function stops if the input isn't strictly alphabetically, which this doesn't do. (in my case, this one is actually more preferable)

Answer (score 10):

Kevin M's solution is compact and elegant. It's got one tiny error, though: the regular expression used with the replace function doesn't limit substitution to alphabetic characters. The `[A-z]` character range includes punctuation characters (`[``\``` ] ^ _ ` ``), which will be swapped for letters when they should be left alone.

The fixed version looks like this:

```
function r(a,b){return++b?String.fromCharCode((a<"["?91:123)>(a=a.charCodeAt()+13)?a:a-26):a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,r)}
```

It's still only 116 bytes. Remarkably small and quite clever.

(Sorry for the full answer posting; I'm still lacking the 50 rep required to post this as a comment to Kevin's excellent answer.)

Answer (score 5):

```
var rot13 = String.prototype.rot13 = function(s)
{
  return (s = (s) ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
  {
    if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
    c = _.charCodeAt(0)>=96;
    k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96 + 12) % 26 + 1;
    return String.fromCharCode(k + (c ? 96 : 64));
  }
  ).join('');
};

alert('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.rot13());
yields nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

Mixing zero-based and one-based indices for the lose.  I blame Netscape.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that's 80-columns, doesn't update string.prototype, well indented and reasonably short.

```
function rot13(str) {
  return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(chr) {
    var start = chr <= 'Z' ? 65 : 97;
    return String.fromCharCode(start + (chr.charCodeAt(0) - start + 13) % 26);
  });
}
```

And an example showing it is working:

```
rot13('[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]')
"[nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM]"
rot13(rot13('[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]'))
"[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"
```

Answer (score 4):

One-liner that weighs in at 116 bytes:

```
function r(a,b){return++b?String.fromCharCode((a<"["?91:123)>(a=a.charCodeAt()+13)?a:a-26):a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,r)}
```

Usage:

`r('The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog.');`

Comment: Everything in JavaScript is a one-liner.... till you format it in the proper human-readable way.

Answer (score 3):

Combining various techniques here, I came up with this 78 character JavaScript ES6 function, which works on Node:

```
rot13=s=>s.replace(/[a-z]/ig,c=>Buffer([((d=Buffer(c)[0])&95)<78?d+13:d-13]));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is still room for enhancement, checking (c<="Z") is actually a check against the codepoint (that we need later on), following that idea gives us a win !

//versus Kevin M's  style :  115 chars (vs 116)
//102 chars with nodejs Buffer (see below)

```
function r(a,b){return++b?String.fromCharCode(((a=a.charCodeAt())<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13):a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,r)}
//nodejs style
function r(a,b){return++b?Buffer([((a=Buffer(a)[0])<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13]):a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,r)}
```

//versus Ben Alpert style : 107 chars (vs 112)
//93 chars with nodejs Buffer (see below)

```
s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(a){return String.fromCharCode(((a=a.charCodeAt())<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13)});
//nodejs style
s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(a){return Buffer([((a=Buffer(a)[0])<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13])})
```

// Same code, formated for production

```
String.prototype.rot13 = function() {
  return this.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(a){
    return String.fromCharCode(((a=a.charCodeAt())<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13);
  });
}
```

In nodejs, you can use Buffer to cast/serialize codepoints, e.g. :

```
var a=65;
""+Buffer([a])           == "A" // note that the cast is done automatically if needed
String.fromCharCode(a)   == "A"

var b="A";
Buffer(a)[0]             == 65
a.charCodeAt()           == 65
```

Comment: Using nodejs Buffer is a total WIN
`function r(a,b){return++b?Buffer([((a=Buffer(a)[0])<91?78:110)>a?a+13:a-13]):a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,r)}`

Comment: Great idea to use Buffer!

Comment: +1 on the Ben Alpert style for Nodejs. I did some heavy performance testing in nodejs and Ben's is very fast and  was slightly better than the Kevin M style. Also, no recursion with the Ben's algorithm.

Comment: @131 - Typo in your Buffer cast/serialize comment. You don't use variable b after initializing.

Comment: Using a framework library doesn't make code shorter, it add more weight to the browser by way of having to load the library first before the code can be used, if possible, use native (javascript) based code, if you have already loaded the library for use on many other elements, then thats one option but to load a library just to do a ROT13 is just a waste of time and bandwidth and data allowance.

Answer (score 2):

My golfed version is 82 bytes long (vs. Ben Albert, which is 35% heavier, but inspired mine):

`S.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>String.fromCharCode((c=c.charCodeAt())+((c&95)>77?-13:13)))`

Differences:

- case-insensitive to catch only English alphabet.
- arrow functions without return and braces.
- delete parameters from charCodeAt.
- test against code insted of string.
- doing +13-26=-13.
- test uppercased (`&95`) against 77 (78+13=91, overflow).

---

Extra: If you want to perform ROT5 on digits, add:
`.replace(/\d/gi,c=>(c>4?-5:5)+c*1)`

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a JavaScript library that performs ROT-n letter substitution: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/rot

> *rot* is a JavaScript library that performs rotational letter substitution. It can be used to shift any ASCII letters in the input string by a given number of positions in the alphabet. To ROT-13 the string `'abc'`, for example:
>
> ```
> // ROT-13 is the default
> rot('abc');
> // → 'nop'
>
> // Or, specify `13` explicitly:
> rot('abc', 13);
> // → 'nop'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is in no way trying to compete with the excellent stuff here, as you see I can't comment but I have my own novice attempt to write this in JS and getting it to work before I read more elegant solutions here - I'm going to share it here.

I tried to write it with `indexOf`, a `switch`, by adding 13, by `String.fromCharCode()` and `CharCodeAt()`. They were getting too long - the helper function in this one is unnecessary but this was my shortest : )

```
function rot13(string) { 
  var result = '', 
      store,
      str = string.toLowerCase();  

  //helper function
  function strgBreak(a){
    var result = [];
    return result = a.split('');
  }

  //rot13 arrays
  var alphArr = strgBreak('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  var inverseArr = strgBreak('nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm');

 for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
     if (alphArr.indexOf( str[i] ) !== -1) {
        result += inverseArr[ alphArr.indexOf( str[i] ) ];
    } else result += str[i];
  }
 return result.toUpperCase(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modern approach to the ROT13 substitution cipher:

```js
const ROT13 = s =>
  s.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c =>
    String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt() + 13 - 26 * /[n-z]/i.test(c)));

console.log(ROT13('The quick brown fox jumps over 13 lazy dogs.'));
```

---

The result of the test case above is:

**Gur dhvpx oebja sbk whzcf bire 13 ynml qbtf.**

Answer (score 0):

While I *really* like the RegEx solution, I primarily undertook the project to see if I could get it done. Glad to report that I finally did manage to do so:

```
String.prototype.rot13 = rot13 = function(s)
 {
    return (s ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
     {
        if (!_.match(/[A-za-z]/)) return _;
        c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
        k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 83) % 26 || 26;
        return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
     }).join('');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript version of @ben-alpert 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/617685/1320932):

```
string.replace /[a-zA-Z]/g, (c) -> String.fromCharCode if (if c <= 'Z' then 90 else 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) then c else c - 26
```

Or as function:

```
ROT13 = (string) -> string.replace /[a-zA-Z]/g, (c) -> String.fromCharCode if (if c <= 'Z' then 90 else 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) then c else c - 26
ROT13('asd') # Returns: 'nfq'
```

Answer (score 0):

My favourite and simple to understand version of decision ROT13

```
function rot13(message) {
  var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  var b = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM"
  return message.replace(/[a-z]/gi, c => b[a.indexOf(c)])
}
```

`a` - classic alphabet, `b` - prepered dictionary with 13th replacement, `return` result with simple RegEx replacement