# ROT-13 function in java?

Tags: java, rot13

Is there already a `rot13()` and `unrot13()` implementation as part of one of the standard Java libraries?  Or do I have to write it myself and "reinvent the wheel"?

It might look something like this:

```
int rot13 ( int c ) { 
  if ( (c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z') ) 
    c=(((c-'A')+13)%26)+'A';

  if ( (c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z') )
    c=(((c-'a')+13)%26)+'a';

  return c; 
}
```

Comment: @BNL I personally prefer rot104.  Requires a dedicated coprocessor though

Comment: @BNL LOL who said it's for security purposes? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928903/what-are-some-practical-applications-of-the-rot13-algorithm)

Comment: By the way, rot13 is its own inverse, so you don't actually need an "unrot13" method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't think it's part of Java by default, but here's an example of how you can implement it;

```
public class Rot13 { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if       (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') c += 13;
            else if  (c >= 'A' && c <= 'M') c += 13;
            else if  (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') c -= 13;
            else if  (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z') c -= 13;
            System.out.print(c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Source: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Rot13.java.html

Answer (score 30):

Might as well contribute my function to save other developers the valuable seconds

```
public static String rot13(String input) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
       char c = input.charAt(i);
       if       (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') c += 13;
       else if  (c >= 'A' && c <= 'M') c += 13;
       else if  (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') c -= 13;
       else if  (c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z') c -= 13;
       sb.append(c);
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this into a method.

Comment: Did you also copy http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Rot13.java.html ?

Comment: how can I add numbers to this function? 0-9 i want to rotate a-zA-Z0-9, kind of a caseSensitive rot18

Answer (score 1):

```
private final static List<String> upperAlphabets = Arrays.asList(
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
        "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N",
        "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
private final static List<String> lowerAlphabets = Arrays.asList(
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
        "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
        "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
        "v", "w", "x", "y", "z");

 private static void rot(int toSkip, String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int pos = 0, newPos = 0;
        boolean upper;
        for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
            pos = upperAlphabets.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));
            if (pos == -1) {
                pos = lowerAlphabets.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));
                upper = false;
            } else {
                upper = true;
            }

            if (pos + toSkip > 25) {
                newPos = (pos + toSkip) % 26;
            } else {
                newPos = pos + toSkip;
            }

            if (upper) {
                sb.append(upperAlphabets.get(newPos));
            } else {
                sb.append(lowerAlphabets.get(newPos));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

This is not only about rot13, this can do rot100 or rot1213 anything depending upon what value you are passing and the most important thing is that both list of upper case and lower case alphabets are must.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes inputs might have special characters, so it's better to include them.

```
    String input = "Do you have any cat pictures?";
    StringBuilder op = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);

        if (c == ' ') {
            op.append(" ");
        } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            if (c > 'm') c -= 13;
            else c += 13;
            op.append(c);
        } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            if (c > 'M') c -= 13;
            else c += 13;
            op.append(c);
        } else {
            op.append(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String rot13(String message) {
     String a  = "";
     
     for(int i =0; i<message.length(); i++){
       if(message.charAt(i)>=65 && message.charAt(i)<=77 ||
          message.charAt(i)>=97 && message.charAt(i)<=109 ){
         a +=  (char)(message.charAt(i)+13);
         
       }
      
       else if(message.charAt(i)>=78 && message.charAt(i)<=90||
          message.charAt(i)>=110 && message.charAt(i)<=122 ){
         a +=  (char)(message.charAt(i)-13);
         
       }
         else {
           a +=  (char)(message.charAt(i));
         }
       
       
       
     }
     
     return a;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

you be doing like dis:

pblic class Rot13 {

```
pblic static void main(Strng[] args) {
    String s = args[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.chrAt(i);
        if       (c >= 'a' & c <= 'm') c += 13;
        els if  (c >= 'A' & c <= 'M') c += 13;
        els if  (c >= 'n' & c <= 'z') c -= 13;
        els if  (c >= 'N' & c <= 'Z') c -= 13;
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Why copy the accepted message and make it worse by breaking the formatting and deleting some characters? What's the point of that?