# Shift character in Alphabet

Tags: java, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ROT-13 function in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981296/rot-13-function-in-java)

I have to shift all char from a string 13 places in the alphabet

```
private static String encode(String line) {
    char[] toEncode = line.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < toEncode.length; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(toEncode[i])) {
            toEncode[i] += 13;
        }
    }
    line = String.valueOf(toEncode);
    return line;
}
```

The Problem is that for example 'z' get to a ?. How can I solve that?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because next chars after 'z' is punctuation chars and so on. You can shift so that 'z' will be 'n' for example.

```
toEncode[i] = (toEncode[i] + 13 - (int)'a') % 26 + (int)'a';
```

Comment: I know that this thread has been on here for quite some time now but I thought it would be worth posting this anyway for future reference. I think that you have a typo in your formula. Should it not be ...% 26... instead of 25 ? Since we want 'z' to shift to 'a' and not to 'b'.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I'm mistakingly assumed that is alphabet consists of 25 letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(('z'+ (char)13)); //output -135
System.out.println((char)('z'+ (char)13)); //output - ?
```

Comment: @ Chandra Sekhar : Thanks for the answer: Please add explanations and guiding instructions for 'homework' questions .

Answer (score 0):

If the calculated char is greater than the last letter (z => 122 or Z => 90) just substract the value of the last letter from the calculated value. You find these numbers all over the internet, e.g. [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).