# Resetting character when end is reached java

Tags: java

Take following code as base:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{   
    alphabet[i] = (char) ('A'+  i );
}
```

My question is: -

If 'A' Changes to 'X' how can we achieve the alphabet to reset from the start?

For example XYZABC

Comment: Possible hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981296/rot-13-function-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have something that should "wrap around", have a look at the modulo operator. The basic idea is: you don't want to count from i=0 to 26, but e.g. from i=23 to 49, but only add the modulo-26 value to it.

Instead of starting to count at 23 (which would be kind of `'X' - 'A'`), you can directly integrate this offset into your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{   
    alphabet[i] = (char) ('A' + ('X' - 'A' +  i) % 26);
}
```

`'A'` is the base, `'X' - 'A'` builds that offset where you add `i` to, and then take the modulo of 26 (as the alphabet has 26 characters), and then add that to your 'A' again.

Answer (score 2):

You can just insert an if statement:

```
char startChar = 'X';

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    char ch = (char) (startChar + i);
    if (ch > 'Z') {
        ch -= 26;
    }
    alphabet[i] = ch;
}
```