# Java- shifting a ROT13 string

Tags: java, string, methods, rot13

I want to shift a ROT13 string by a user-inputted amount. This is the sample output:

```
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Enter amount to shift text by: 3

ORIGINAL: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

ENCRYPTED: defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
```

The user MUST provide a shift value between 0 and 26. If the user goes out of this range, the program should force the user to enter a valid value:

```
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
Enter amount to shift text by: -3
ERROR! Shift must be non-negative!
Enter amount to shift text by: 33
ERROR! Shift must be no more than 26!
Enter amount to shift text by: 2
```

Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): !!!
   Goodbye!

This is my code that I have written:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab08b 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input = getText(sc);
    int shift = getShift(sc);
    if (input.equals("!!!"))
    {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }

    while (!input.equals("!!!"))
    {
        String encoded = rot13(input);
        shiftMessage(input, shift);
        displayResults(input, encoded);
        input = getText(sc);
        if (input.equals("!!!"))
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }


}
private static int getShift (Scanner inScanner)
{
    System.out.print("Enter amount to shift text by: ");
    int shift = inScanner.nextInt();

    if (shift < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Shift must be non-negative!");
        System.out.print("Enter amount to shift text by: ");
        shift = inScanner.nextInt();
    }
    else if (shift > 26)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Shift must be non-negative!");
        System.out.print("Enter amount to shift text by: ");
        shift = inScanner.nextInt();
    }
    return shift;
}

private static String getText(Scanner inScanner)
{
    System.out.print("Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): ");
    String original = inScanner.nextLine();

    while (original.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR! String must not be empty!");
        System.out.print("Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): ");
        original = inScanner.nextLine();
    }
    return original;
}


private static String rot13(String input)
{
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch = (char) (ch + 13);
            if (ch > 'Z')
            {
                ch = (char)(ch - 26);
            }
        }
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
            ch = (char)(ch + 13);
            if (ch > 'z')
            {
                ch = (char)(ch - 26);
            }
        }
        str = str + ch;
    }
    return str;
}

private static void displayResults(String inText, String encText)
{
    System.out.print("+");
    for (int i = 13 + encText.length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println("+");

    System.out.println("| ORIGINAL:  " + inText + " |");
    System.out.println("| ENCRYPTED: " + encText + " |");

    System.out.print("+");
    for(int i = 13 + encText.length(); i > 0; i--){
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println("+");
}

private static String shiftMessage(String input, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        input = input.charAt(input.length()- n) + input.substring(0,input.length());
    }
    return input;
}
```

}

**UPDATE**: THIS CODE IS HOW I HAVE PROGRESSED.
The actual shifting still does not work
http://pastebin.com/v2T1fxEj

I have it printing out the ROT13 encryption and everything, I just don't know how to shift it.

also, when I try to add the "Enter amount to shift by" in the main method below String input = getText(sc), I just end up getting this:

```
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): ERROR! String must not be empty!
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit):
```

I am not supposed to get that

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Show your code in the question please. This question will not be useful to others if they come along later and the link is broken.

Comment: oh ok. I thought it would be easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROT-13 function in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981296/rot-13-function-in-java)

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I have completed the actual ROT. I cannot find how to do the shifting though.

Comment: Change `13` to `n` in `rot13`.

Comment: I just added a new method to get the shift amount, but I still get that problem where is says ERROR!

Comment: @saka1029 why? Wouldn't that mess up the encryption?

Comment: based on the example you would use substring. Assuming shift == 3, here is how you would write it encoded.substring(3) + encoded.substring(0, 3)

Comment: 3 was just an example, it could be from 0 to 26 shift

Comment: No, I get the actual encryption, and then it follows with Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): ERROR! String must not be empty!
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit):

Comment: I am still trying to work out how to shift it.

Comment: @ConfusedCoder: Replace 3 with whatever is the shift value. Just validate the length of encrypted string before shifting.

Comment: that didnt really work

Comment: @ConfusedCoder: can you be specific on what didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shiftMessage()` is like `rot13()`, only put in `n` instead of `13`:

```
private static String shiftMessage(String input, int n) {
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch = (char) (ch + n);
            if (ch > 'Z')
            {
                ch = (char)(ch - 26);
            }
        }
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
            ch = (char)(ch + n);
            if (ch > 'z')
            {
                ch = (char)(ch - 26);
            }
        }
        str = str + ch;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Now when I call `shiftMessage()` instead of `rot13()` from `main()`, I can:

```
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Enter amount to shift text by: 1
+---------------------------------------+
| ORIGINAL:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| ENCRYPTED: bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Other issues:

`ERROR! String must not be empty!`, which you mention, is a classic with `Scanner.nextInt()`. `nextInt()` only reads the number, not the newline following it. So when you subsequently do `inScanner.nextLine()`, it reads the newline and returns an empty string. I believe the solution is to call `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` to get rid of the newline.

Last, you cannot know in advance that the user will only type an incorrect shift amount once. I can do:

```
Enter your text to encrypt (!!! to quit): abc
Enter amount to shift text by: -3
ERROR! Shift must be non-negative!
Enter amount to shift text by: -3
+----------------+
| ORIGINAL:  abc |
| ENCRYPTED: ^_` |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! However, whenever I tried to add nextLine(), eclipse complained and said that it can't invoke nextLine() on the primitive type int. Is there another fix for that? For the last thing you said, I realized that I can fix that by just using a while loop, I was using an if-statement, so it would mess up the encryption if i was out of bounds more than once

Comment: I’m not an expert on `Scanner`. The message sounds like you were trying `inScanner.nextInt().nextLine()` or something. Rather try `inScanner.nextLine();` on a separate line.

Comment: Ahhh never mind. I got it. I ended up just changing [nextLine()] in [getText] to just [next()]