# How can I pass hrefs to my method in Vue js with `@click`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am following the accepted answer of this question: [Hide links from Google via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826800/hide-links-from-google-via-javascript)

I want to pass the href to my method `linkAction()`, how can I achieve this with an `@click`?

This is what I have so far

```
<template>
    <span
      href="https://www.w3schools.com/" <-- some url
      @click="linkAction(this)"
    >
      Link to W3 Schools 
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MainContent extends Vue {
  linkAction(e: any): any {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

</script>
```

I am getting on my console: `null`. Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: so you can see 'null' in the console when you click? So the click handler is rigged up, I'm guessing that 'this' isn't a known keyword in the 'template' - if you just do, @click="linkAction"  - I think you might get the 'this' for free in the 'e' var

Comment: No need to hard-code it, no need to use ref's: just access it via the event target inside your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template you need to change `@click="linkAction(this)"` to `@click="linkAction($event)"`.

And in method `linkAction` you do something like this:

```
linkAction(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not accessible from template

but you can simply use `ref` attribute and then use `this.$refs` to get element

```
<template>
    <span
      ref="link"
      href="https://www.w3schools.com/" <-- some url
      @click="linkAction"
    >
      Link to W3 Schools 
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MainContent extends Vue {
  linkAction(): any {
    console.log(this.$refs.link);
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to make `link` as part of your component's `data`, and then use it in the `linkAction` method.

```
<template>
    <span
      :href="link" 
      @click="linkAction">
      Link to W3 Schools 
    </span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MainContent extends Vue {
  data(): any {
     return {
        link: 'https://www.w3schools.com/'
     }
  },

  linkAction(): any {
    console.log(this.link);
  }
}

</script>
```