# Implement ROT13 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rot13

I have a JS function that reads variable `i` as is. I'd like to pass this variable encoded with ROT13, so my function would first have to decode the variable and then continue.

The problem is how to make the JS decode it and use it.

I've found a JS [implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_rot13/) for ROT13, but I have no clue where to include this in my function:

```
{{
_inst.gmlimgp=parameter_string( 1 );
_inst.gmlsp=string_pos( "i=", _inst.gmlimgp );
if ((_inst.gmlsp!=0)) {{
_inst.gmlsp+=2;
_inst.gmlimgp=string_copy( _inst.gmlimgp, _inst.gmlsp, string_length( _inst.gmlimgp ) );
g_pBuiltIn.background_index[1]=3;
background_replace( g_pBuiltIn.background_index[1], _inst.gmlimgp, 0, 0 );
_inst.set_sprite_index( (-4) );
}
;}
 else {{
show_message( "invalid parameter" );
}
;};
}
;}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like ROT13! `:(`

Comment: I can't make any sense of how the text of your question applies to the code you've provided. There doesn't appear to be a variable named `i` read by any function (unless the `"i="` is passed to `eval` at some point? If so, that's totally unclear what what you've given here). You should clearly identify what function/line is giving you difficulty, and also show any attempts you've tried to make it work (and what errors you got, if any).

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as ROT13 in JavaScript:

> ERRONEOUS <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/617647/462627)</sup>
>
> ```
> <script>
> String.prototype.rot13 = rot13 = function(s)
>  {
>     return (s = (s) ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
>      {
>         if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
>         c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
>         k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96) % 26 + 13;
>         return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
>      }).join('');
>  };
> </script>
> ```

Or shorter version:

```
s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});
```

**Reference:** [Where is my one-line implementation of rot13 in JavaScript going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/617647/462627)

To pass this variable `i`, you do this:

```
getRot13Input (i.rot13());
```

Comment: The code I have pasted reads a variable `i` as is - i.e. straight. It does not pass it, it does not encode it. I however will pass the variable `i` to the JS encoded with ROT13 and am looking for a way to make my JS first decode it and then continue as it was.

Comment: I expect this was downvoted because it's not apparent that the OP has had any difficulty with building a working ROT13 implementation. It appears the problem lies in *applying* a ROT13 function to the code provided in the question. I don't understand *how* the OP wants to apply ROT13 to the code in the question, so I can't answer, but it seems likely that this answer solves a problem that is independent of the OP's problem.

Comment: Code fails 'Bacon'.rot13() is coming out to 'Onp|{' when it should be 'Onpba'.

Comment: @georgeawg Ah okay. But it's been posted 4 years ago.

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy solution:

```
//This function take rot13 encoded string and decoded it as simple string.
function rot13(str) { 
  var arr = str.split('');
  var newArray = [];

 var first = {
  'A' : 'N',
  'B' : 'O',
  'C' : 'P',
  'D' : 'Q',
  'E' : 'R',
  'F' : 'S',
  'G' : 'T',
  'H' : 'U',
  'I' : 'V',
  'J' : 'W',
  'K' : 'X',
  'L' : 'Y',
  'M' : 'Z'
 };

var rest = {
'N' : 'A',
'O' : 'B',
'P' : 'C',
'Q' : 'D',
'R' : 'E',
'S' : 'F',
'T' : 'G',
'U' : 'H',
'V' : 'I',
'W' : 'J',
'X' : 'K',
'Y' : 'L',
'Z' : 'M'
};

// Iteration though the string array(arr)
for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){

  if (first.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){       //checking first obj has the element or not

    newArray.push(first[arr[i]]);           //Pushing the element to the nerarray

  } else if(rest.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){   //checking rest obj has the element or not

    newArray.push(rest[arr[i]]);
  } else {
    newArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
}
return newArray.join('');
}


rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");  //call the function with rot13 encoded string
```

Answer (score 0):

Add after

```
_inst.gmlimgp=string_copy( _inst.gmlimgp, _inst.gmlsp, string_length( _inst.gmlimgp ) );
```

but before

```
g_pBuiltIn.background_index[1]=3;
```

the line to call str_rot13 like so

```
_inst.gmlimgp= global.str_rot13(_inst.glomgp);
```

PS i assume that you include the str_rot13 functin as a property of global object.

Comment: `PS i assume that you include the str_rot13 functin as a property of global object.` - could you elaborate?