# Letter replace in textbox

Tags: html, replace, character, inputbox

I'm trying to recreate a text converter ultimately simular to [rot13.com](http://www.rot13.com/). However I don't know how to make it convert specific characters to another character. If I wanted to input;

> example

Then I would want the output to be

> rcszqar

Some more;

> abc > snv
>
> foo > gpp
>
> bar > nst

I'm using `return String.fromCharCode((c <= 'Z' ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + i) ? c : c - 26);`

But no matter what numbers I change in that line, none of them are replaced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The function is documented here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/617685/987044

```
        function rot(s, i) {            return s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function (c) {
                return String.fromCharCode((c <= 'Z' ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + i) ? c : c - 26);            });         }       function update() {             document.getElementById('output').value = rot(document.getElementById('input').value,
+document.getElementById('rot').value);         }
```

The only number you need to change is the variable `i` when calling the function. For example

```
rot ("example", 13);//->"rcszqar"
```