# Cesar's Cypher method repeating the last letter of each word

Tags: javascript

I'm making Cesar's Cypher that shifts the letters 13 places. It works, but the last letter of each word is repeated. I know there is probably a more efficient way to write this, but here is my code.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var word = "";
  var z = 30;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.substring(i, i + 1) === " ") {
      word = word + str.substring(i, i + 1);
    }

    for (x = 0; x < letters.length; x++) {
      if (str.substring(i, i + 1) === letters[x]) {
        z = x; //18
      }
    }

    var n = z + 13; //31
    if (n >= 26) {
      word = word + letters[13 - (26 - z)];
    } else if (n < 26)
      word = word + letters[13 + z];
  }

  return word;
}


rot13("LBH QVQ VG!");
```

For example LBH QVQ VG! prints out YOU UDID DITT instead of YOU DID IT!. Also, I'm new to javascript so if any syntax looks off please correct me.

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time here using a look-up table of the form `{ a: "m", b: "n" ... }` where you can do a straight up substitution on each letter with `replace` using a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my one-line implementation of rot13 in JavaScript going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617647/where-is-my-one-line-implementation-of-rot13-in-javascript-going-wrong)

Comment: @MaciejKwas That doesn't explain what he did wrong here.

Comment: If you really want to learn programming, this seems like a nice opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you should `continue;` the for loop if you detect a space (otherwise your last used character gets appended a second time):

```
if (str.substring(i, i + 1) === " ") {
  word += " ";
  continue;
}
```

Your second problem is that you don't care if the current character isn't found in your `letters` array, in that case your code simply uses the last `z`.

Just as a sidenote: In your position I would take a look at JS' built-in functions, for example `split`, `indexOf`, `charCodeAt`, `fromCharCode`, which can simplify your life quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you find a space and copy it to the result, you don't skip over the rest of the code that processes the character. Since the loop that sets `z` never finds a match, it uses the value of `z` from the previous iteration of the loop, so it duplicates the last character of the previous word.

The same thing happens if there's a punctuation character. In this case, the code that tests for space doesn't copy it to the result, then you go into the loop that looks for the character in `letters`, it doesn't find it, so it again uses the previous value of `z`.

A simple solution for both is to check whether the current character is in `letters`, rather than checking specifically for `space`.

BTW, you can use `str[i]` or `str.charAt(i)` to get the current character in the string, rather than `str.substring(i, i+1)`. And to find an element of an array, use `letters.indexOf(char)` instead of an explicit loop.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var word = "";
  var z = 30;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var char = str[i];
    z = letters.indexOf(char);
    if (z == -1) {
      word += char;
      continue;
    }

    var n = z + 13; //31
    if (n >= 26) {
      word = word + letters[13 - (26 - z)];
    } else if (n < 26)
      word = word + letters[13 + z];
  }

  return word;
}


console.log(rot13("LBH QVQ VG!"));
```

And instead of your `if` statement at the end, you can use the modulus operator:

```
word += letters[n % letters.length];
```